# Regex: Check value after a specific string

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like following: `["StringA":8,"StringB":50,"StringC":286]`.
Now I want to check, if the **value** after **"StringA"** is less than **10**. So **"StringA":1** to **"StringA":9** should match, but **"StringA":12** or **"StringA":318** should not match.

I tried `("Data":[0-9])` but that doesn't work really.

Comment: Regex isn't a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready *not* to match *zero-padded* values like `"StringA":01` (`01` is technically possible value *less* than `10`) you can try *negative look ahead*

```
  "Data":[0-9](?![0-9])
```

i.e. `"Data":` followed by *single* digit and *not* followed by second digit. If you want to include *zero-padded* values, add `0*`:

```
  "Data":0*[0-9](?![0-9])
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be sufficiant:

```
"StringA"\s*:\s*(\d)\b
```

Regex [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YVAXSQ/1) with explanation

```js
var s ='["StringA":8,"StringB":50,"StringC":286,"StringA":44]';
console.log(s.match(/"StringA"\s*:\s*(\d)\b/g));
```

Comment: Works also perfectly!